# Image Dimensions Issue in HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have the following code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather|Open+Sans');

.container1{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.square:hover {
    -webkit-transform: translate(20px, -10px);
    -ms-transform: translate(10px, -10px);
    transform: translate(10px, -10px);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
     }


.square{
    height: 430px;
    background: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px #D9DBDF;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease; 
}

.mask{
  clip: rect(0px, 460px, 220px, 0px);
  position: absolute;
  border: 5px solid #555;
}


.h11{
  margin: auto;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 240px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  font-size: 24px;
}
p9 {
  text-align: justify;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #C8C8C8;
  line-height: 18px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  display: block;
}

.button56 {
    background-color: #3EDD84;
    color: white;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 70px;
    font-size: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: 'merriweather';
}
```

```html
  <section>
                  <div class="section-title">
    <h2>Featured Blogs Of The Day</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="parent-div">
    <div class="child-div">
      <div class="blogmaster">
        <div class="column1">
          <div class="row1">
            <div class="container1">
              <div class="square">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1504610926078-a1611febcad3?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=e1c8fe0c9197d66232511525bfd1cc82&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1100&q=80" class="mask" style="border: 5px solid #555">
                <div class="h11">“Chances Of My Uni/College Admission?”</div>
                <p9>It is that time of the year again (yay!) where we — high school students — are supposed to fill out the applications and land in our dream Universities/Colleges!</p9>

                <div><a href="https://m-hussainomer03.medium.com/chances-of-my-uni-college-admission-20bc0efec0af" target="_" class="button56">Read More</a></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- new start of blog -->
    <div class="parent-div">
      <div class="child-div">
        <div class="blogmaster">
          <div class="column1">
            <div class="row1">
              <div class="container1">
                <div class="square">
                  <img src="https://www.isfasports.gr/image/cache/data/products/pr_3-1100x1100.jpg" class="mask" style="border: 5px solid #555">
                  <div class="h11">My Career Advice To You: Take These Steps...</div>
                  <p9>Humans tend to make mistakes — and its completely normal as it results in the growth and development of an individual — either psychologically or physically.</p9>

                  <div><a href="https://m-hussainomer03.medium.com/my-career-advice-to-you-take-these-steps-to-ultimate-prosperity-6c0687ce9c9f" target="_" class="button56">Read More</a></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      

      
    </section><!-- End blogs Section -->
```

How would I modify the `.mask` class which controls the image, so that whatever device you use to view the two cards, the width of the image **always** fits the card?

For example, I have the above code embedded in a website, and so when I use a smaller device to view the website, the width of the image changes.

This is my output on a smaller device:

[image]

I could not show the second card but it is the exact same as this card above. See how the image's width is not fitted on the card?

However, on a large screen, this is my output:

[image]

**Now, the image is fitted perfectly, and this is what I want on smaller devices too.**

Is there a way to modify the `.mask` class so that whatever device the user is on, the image is always fitted on the box like shown in the output right above? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

How about the following. Adding `width: 100%; height: auto` to images should make them scale better.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather|Open+Sans');
.container1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.square:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translate(20px, -10px);
  -ms-transform: translate(10px, -10px);
  transform: translate(10px, -10px);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

.square {
  width: 100%;
  /**/
  min-height: 430px;
  /**/
  background: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px #D9DBDF;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.mask {
  clip: rect(0px, 460px, 220px, 0px);
  border: 5px solid #555;
  width: calc(100% - (2 * 5px));
  /**/
  height: auto;
  /**/
}

.h11 {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 24px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  font-size: 24px;
}

p9 {
  text-align: justify;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #C8C8C8;
  line-height: 18px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  display: block;
}

.button56 {
  background-color: #3EDD84;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 70px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  /**/
  //*or margin: 15px 70px 15px 30px;*/
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'merriweather';
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="section-title">
    <h2>Featured Blogs Of The Day</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="parent-div">
    <div class="child-div">
      <div class="blogmaster">
        <div class="column1">
          <div class="row1">
            <div class="container1">
              <div class="square">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1504610926078-a1611febcad3?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=e1c8fe0c9197d66232511525bfd1cc82&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1100&q=80" class="mask" style="border: 5px solid #555">
                <div class="h11">“Chances Of My Uni/College Admission?”</div>
                <p9>It is that time of the year again (yay!) where we — high school students — are supposed to fill out the applications and land in our dream Universities/Colleges!</p9>

                <div><a href="https://m-hussainomer03.medium.com/chances-of-my-uni-college-admission-20bc0efec0af" target="_" class="button56">Read More</a></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- new start of blog -->
    <div class="parent-div">
      <div class="child-div">
        <div class="blogmaster">
          <div class="column1">
            <div class="row1">
              <div class="container1">
                <div class="square">
                  <img src="https://www.isfasports.gr/image/cache/data/products/pr_3-1100x1100.jpg" class="mask" style="border: 5px solid #555">
                  <div class="h11">My Career Advice To You: Take These Steps...</div>
                  <p9>Humans tend to make mistakes — and its completely normal as it results in the growth and development of an individual — either psychologically or physically.</p9>

                  <div><a href="https://m-hussainomer03.medium.com/my-career-advice-to-you-take-these-steps-to-ultimate-prosperity-6c0687ce9c9f" target="_" class="button56">Read More</a></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>





</section>
<!-- End blogs Section -->
```

Comment: That is not what I am looking for, the image heght should be what it is in the code I sent above, its just the width that needs modification

Comment: is there a way to modify the width only of the image and make it fit the box on smaller screens?